Filter against multiple strings for an element
I have data like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TRANSFER xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.interlis.ch/INTERLIS2.3" xmlns="http://www.interlis.ch/INTERLIS2.3">
  <HEADERSECTION VERSION="2.3" SENDER="Holenstein Ingenieure AG">
    <MODELS>
      <MODEL NAME="SIA405_WASSER_2015_LV95" VERSION="05.10.2018" URI="http://www.sia.ch/405" />
    </MODELS>
  </HEADERSECTION>
  <DATASECTION>
    <SIA405_WASSER_2015_LV95.SIA405_Wasser BID="ch152ck800000002">
      <SIA405_WASSER_2015_LV95.SIA405_Wasser.Leitung TID="ch17fnufWDNTSs6C">
        <OBJ_ID>ch17fnufWDNTSs6C</OBJ_ID>
      </SIA405_WASSER_2015_LV95.SIA405_Wasser.Leitung>
      <SIA405_WASSER_2015_LV95.SIA405_Wasser.Absperrorgan TID="ch17fnuf3f5P2bPQ">
        <OBJ_ID>ch17fnuf3f5P2bPQ</OBJ_ID>
        <SymbolOri>115.1</SymbolOri>
        <Lagebestimmung>genau</Lagebestimmung>
      </SIA405_WASSER_2015_LV95.SIA405_Wasser.Absperrorgan>
    </SIA405_WASSER_2015_LV95.SIA405_Wasser>
  </DATASECTION>
</TRANSFER>

In DATASECTION, there are nodes with different names and different structure, but every has the element OBJ_ID. In reality, the file has 20000 - 40000 nodes with unique OBJ_ID. On the other side, I have a list (text file) with hundreds of OBJ_IDs. The tasks are now:

a) create a new XML with all the nodes where the OBJ_ID is defined in the list
b) create a new XML where all the nodes on the list are removed (not copied)

based on the thread here
How to compare against multiple strings in xslt I tried this, but with no success:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:ili="http://www.interlis.ch/INTERLIS2.3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <!-- externally-specified parameter -->
  <xsl:param name="pNames">
    <n>ch17fnufWDNTUJxA</n>
    <n>ch17fnufWDNTUJto</n>
    <n>ch17fnufWDNTUJoN</n>
  </xsl:param>
  <xsl:template match="ili:DATASECTION//node()">
    <xsl:if test="@OBJ_ID = $pNames/*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

The main target is to find a solution where a can find the package of hundreds OBJ_ID in a small way and to avoid to repeat simple match / select / if again and again.
Thanks again in advance for your help!

Your input example  is not a well-formed XML document!

Your question is not entirely clear. First, in XSLT 1.0 you can only produce a single result in each transformation (unless your processor supports an extension such as EXSLT exsl:document). Then there is the question of what should the result be if you have a hierarchical structure of elements, where some elements (e.g. parent and grandchild) appear in the list, and others (e.g. child) do not.

@michael.hor257k
a) shame on me - I fixed the input example now.
b) hierarchy: good question.. In current example there is no structure, only one node and the next. But in other similar data - if there is a structure it should be keep by the way: "when parent is remove also removed children; when child is to be kept then keep the parents"

Does this parameter pNames in your example looks in reality this way with n-nodes?

The idea of "parameter" is copied from the thread linked above, maybe it's not correct. The main target is "find hundreds of nodes based on there OBJ_ID from thousands of existing nodes"

First thing, I would suggest you keep the list of IDs in a separate XML document and pass only the path to the document as the parameter (or hard-code it into the stylesheet). This way you will be dealing with a node-set instead of a string, which will make things much easier.
Now, in order to satisfy your requirement of:

when parent is remove also removed children; when child is to be kept then keep the parents

you could try and do something like:
XSLT 1.0
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ili="http://www.interlis.ch/INTERLIS2.3" 
exclude-result-prefixes="ili">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="ids" select="document('ids.xml')/root/n"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[ili:OBJ_ID]">  
    <xsl:if test="descendant-or-self::ili:OBJ_ID = $ids">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>

where the external ids.xml file has a structure of:
<root>
    <n>ch17fnufWDNTUJxA</n>
    <n>ch17fnufWDNTUJto</n>
    ...
</root>

Caveats:

Not tested very thoroughly;
With hundreds of IDs in the list and 20000 - 40000 elements to process, this is not likely to be fast.


Before going to the weekend my first, quick report: You are my hero! ;-)

Seem to work as expected.
it's quick: "searching" 200 ids in 8000 elements is done in four seconds (on a standard workstation)
Other as described there are also nodes without OBJ_ID, and they are copied too. So I have to modify it a little bit and it will be OK.
Thanks a lot for your help and have a fine weekend!


What I still don't understand why the line
'<xsl:template match="*[ili:OBJ_ID]"> '
also accepts nodes without OBJ_ID.

It doesn't. Any element that does not have a OBJ_ID child is processed by the identity transform template.

Hi @michael.hor257k
I'm not sure if I should open a new thread, but I think the problem is very close to the original one.
In the OT I was asking for "filter against an ELEMENT"; now I need to 'filter against an ATTRIBUTE". The XML is the same as above, but I don't have to check the OBJ_ID but the "TID=..", for example here:
<SIA405_WASSER_2015_LV95.SIA405_Wasser.Leitung TID="ch17fnufWDNTSs6C">
I tried to modify the code from your answer, but I fail with MATCH ...
Any help will be appreciated very much.

I struggle to follow your explanation. It seems like <xsl:template match="*[@TID]"><xsl:if test="descendant-or-self::*/@TID= $ids"> should work. If not, please post this as a new question, with the requisite [mcve].

I'm very glad about your help. Thanks a lot! I wish you a great time!
